# Is it possible to tell if a card is showing on the watch?

Tags: wear-os

I'm creating a watchface for Android wear and I want to change the layout based on if a card is showing or not. I'm sure Google will expose this in the official watchface APIs but is there any way to hack it until then?

I've tried creating a notificaiton listener on the phone but it seems I can't access if a notification is localOnly or not so I can't tell what will show on the watch.

I've tried iterating through the view hierarchy on the watch but it doesn't show me anything useful. Is there a way to access the content views in a window through reflection?

Any help would be appreciated, I'd hate to have to wait for Google to release their API.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any hack for that yet. Making these kind of hacks is very unstable as it can break on any different device or os upgrade and crashes your app (a watchface can crash in loop rendering the device unusable...). I really recommend you to wait a couple of days, they should release it pretty soon now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
I used the onPeekCardPositionUpdate method which sets a rectangle to the bounds of the card.
If no peek card is showing, the top of the rectangle will be 0
And the method is called every time the height of a card changes.
The following card will write the state of a card showing in the boolean yesACardIsShowing.

```
    @Override
    // Rect -> none
    public void onPeekCardPositionUpdate(Rect bounds) {
        super.onPeekCardPositionUpdate(bounds);
        if (!bounds.equals(mCardBounds)) {
            mCardBounds.set(bounds);
            yesACardIsShowing = bounds.top != 0
        }
    }
```